# TypeScript: Any class that implements a particular interface

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this interface

```
interface CanFly {
  fly(): void;
}
```

And I will create two classes, `Bird` and `AirPlane` that both implement the above interface.

And finally, I want to create a function that is `flyIn2Seconds`, which looks like this:

```
function flyIn2Seconds(who: any extends CanFly) {
  setTimeout(() => who.fly(), 2000);
}
```

However `any extends CanFly` doesn't work (`[ts] '?' expected.`). Is there a way to specify the type "any class that implements CanFly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply specify the interface:

```
function flyIn2Seconds(who: CanFly) {
  setTimeout(() => who.fly(), 2000);
}
```

More in [the interfaces documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).